# How to insert a row using a IDbDataAdapter(SqlDataAdapter or OleDbDataAdapter) without loading the entire table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database

I need to insert a row into a DataTable using a OleDbDataAdapter. However, my table has more than 100000 records and I don't want to load all the records.

My current code loads all the records into the DataTable

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Nodes", _cnAq9);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["nID"] = nNodeID;
dr["csNumber"] = strNumber;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
da.Update(dt);
```

Is there a way to insert data into my table without filling my datatable with all the rows other than adding "where 1 = 0" to my statement

EDIT

I need to use a DataAdapter to do this

Comment: yes why not just use a OleDbCommand object after that use ExecuteReader(); method I will post a simple example

Comment: @DJKRAZE Why would you use `ExecuteReader` for an insert?

Comment: Someone should explain why they down voted this question...

Comment: I agree with subt13... It seems someone downvoted my question because I didn't chose his answer... This doesn't encourage me to ask more questions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [FillSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fillschema%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) instead of Fill

As per request:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Nodes", _cnAq9);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["nID"] = nNodeID;
dr["csNumber"] = strNumber;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
da.Update(dt);
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere so I wanted to do a question about this.

Comment: Since your answer has been selected, could you document your answer by putting a code example like the answer from MRM?

Comment: @Goldorak84 - I took it from MRM since you wanted to see the change in code after all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using the [DbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx) class to execute an `INSERT`.

Your code will probably look something like

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO Nodes (nID, csNumber) " +
                "VALUES (?, ?)";

    var command = new OleDbCommand( query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nID", nNodeID);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csNumber", strNumber);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Nice alternative, but I want to do it with the DataAdapter

Answer (score 1):

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Nodes", _cnAq9);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["nID"] = nNodeID;
dr["csNumber"] = strNumber;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
da.Update(dt);
```

Comment: How is this different than my answer I gave over a minute before this one?

Comment: @subt13 This includes code, and believe it or not more than one person can arrive at the same answer at more or less the same time.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - I meant it as a rhetorical question, even though I wasn't asking you.

Comment: @subt13 : although this answer includes code, I chose your answer to be the accepted answer since you wrote it first.

Comment: @MRM : nice answer, but subt13 wrote it before you

Comment: @Goldorak84 - I appreciate it, that's the way it should be :).  Seeing how you already wrote the code I didn't see the need to duplicate it with a single line difference

Answer (score -1):

```
    try   
             oleconnStkNames = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConnectionString);
                oleconnStkNames.Open();                
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = oleconnStkNames; //new OleDbConnection(strAccessConnectionString);
                cmd.CommandText = "TheName of your InsertQuery "; // name of the query you want to run
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // or System.Data.CommandType.Text if you are not using a Access StoredProc
                OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    bla..bla..bla 

}
```

//if you want to wrap it in a using() and add transactional processing use this example that I've written to fit what ever it is you are doing..

```
            using (OleDbCommand olecmdStkNames = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, oleconnStkNames))
            {
                olecmdStkNames.CommandTimeout = 60;
                oletransStockList = oleconnStkNames.BeginTransaction();
                olecmdStkNames.Transaction = oletransStockList;
                olecmdStkNames.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                try
                {
                    intRecordsAffected = olecmdStkNames.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    oletransStockList.Commit();
                   }
                catch (OleDbException oledbExInsert_Update)
                {
                    oletransStockList.Rollback();
                    Console.WriteLine(oledbExInsert_Update.Message);
                }
                ((IDisposable)oletransStockList).Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: I need the answer to be with a DataAdapter

Comment: Because that's the way it is :P

Comment: you have to learn to think outside the box ..just because it is the way it is .. that means you are just following someone elses style. all of the anwsers that were given here will work.. the only thing you have to do is be willing to open your mind.. and not be so myopic in thought.. respectfully speaking

Comment: Did you downvote me because of that? I already had the answer and I wanted to document the use of FillSchema to accomplish what I wanted to do

Comment: It was clearly stated in my question that I want the answer to be with a DataAdapter, why do you question my criteria?